# Wordpress Posts forced to load as Uncategorized

Tags: permalinks

I have a really frustrating issue with my wordpress site. At one point permalinks just started to be forced to load under Uncategorized. This URL for example: https://linuxman.co/linux-software/host-your-own-personal-internet-radio-station-with-azuracast/. If you open it, the URL changes to https://linuxman.co/uncategorized/host-your-own-personal-internet-radio-station-with-azuracast/.

I have debug enabled in wp-config.php but I don't see any errors propagating in the file. I have disabled plugins that I suspect might have something to do with it. I have migrated the website to a fresh Wordpress instance from backup and it still does the same thing.

I'm not a Wordpress expert and have already paid someone to fix it not so long ago, which they did but after a few days, posts went right back to loading as Uncategorized...

I'm not sure where to go from here and I have only found about 4 related issues in Google. Any ideas on what I can try? It is ruining my SEO...

Comment: What are your permalink settings?

Comment: if this happens to every link you have,  its very probable that there is a function somewhere doing this, or in the theme or in a plugin.

Comment: @tiagocalado I did disable plugins and switched themes as well but I still get the same result.

Comment: @bosco I'm using Custom Structure with `/%category%/%postname%/` - This has always worked fine since the beginning, I just don't know what could be causing problems _now_.